# GRE definite integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am prepping for GRE subject and got stuck on yet another integral.

Evaluate $ \displaystyle \int_{-3}^3 xe^{x^2} \cos x - \vert x \vert \,dx$

I broke it into the difference of two integrals where the second is the area of absolute value between $-3$ and $3$ which is $9$! How on earth do I integrate the first part? Can I let $u = x^2$ then do a by parts? thanks in advance just need a tip/hint!

Comment: To do the first part, note it's an odd function.

Comment: If you didn't have the odd function, you COULD have done it with a $u$ substitution. $u=x^2$.  However,  using it is odd is way easier

Comment: as a suggestion for future: the more complicated such "exam-type problems" look, the easier the solution. You just have to find the right symmetry/approach for the problem; leave brute-force as your last resort.

Comment: so it's zero?!?

Comment: @MarkSaving is it zero

Comment: _Not_ entirely odd:  which term of the integrand is _even_?  Can you integrate _that_ easily?

Comment: well both exp and cos are even? only x is odd , no?

Comment: A product of even and odd functions is odd, and only the factor $ \ x \ $ is odd.

Comment: lol you got me more lost now, I know even times odd is odd and odd times odd is even, so we have (odd)(even)(even)?

Comment: apparently $0$ is correct lol the answer was 9 which is the second integral implying the first is identically $0$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame May I know the source of this problem, please?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari it is pulled from UCLA are math subject problems, number 56 https://www.math.ucla.edu/~bonsoon/summer2020/files/problems.pdf

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Thank you. Wish you success in your studies.

Comment: thanks :) you as well!! @Hussain-Alqatari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I = \int_{-3}^{3} xe^{x^2} \cos x - |x| dx$

$I = \int_{-3}^{3} xe^{x^2} \cos x dx - \int_{-3}^{3} |x| dx$

Note that $x$ is odd and $e^{x^2}$ and $\cos x$ are even.

Therefore $xe^{x^2} \cos x$ is odd

Therefore $\int_{-3}^{3} xe^{x^2} \cos x dx = 0$

Note also that $|x|$ is even

Therefore $\int_{-3}^{3} |x| dx = 2 \int_{0}^{3} |x| dx = 2\int_{0}^{3} x dx = 2 [x^2/2]_{0}^{3} = 2(9/2) = 9$

Therefore:

$I = \int_{-3}^{3} xe^{x^2} \cos x dx - \int_{-3}^{3} |x| dx$

$I = 0-9 = -9$

$\int_{-3}^{3} xe^{x^2} \cos x - |x| dx = -9$

Comment: I thought integral from $-a$ to $a$ of odd is zero, you wrote since its even its zero? but since its even its equal to 2 times from $0$ to $a$

Comment: I think its (odd)(even)(even)=(odd)(even)=odd?

Comment: Yes you're right. I've changed that :)